# My Bootstrap carousels are not working

Tags: javascript, html, carousel

My Bootstrap carousels are not working. When I click on the slider left or slider right buttons, the webpage just moves down and #bannerCarousel appears in the browser address bar. As for the "Testimonials" carousel, it is supposed to play automatically, but it doesn't do anything. Can someone please help me resolve this issue?

Here is my HTML and Javascript:

```js
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
        $('.carouselBanner').carousel(),
        $('.carouselTestimonial').carousel()
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>RialedUp</title>
        
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <section class="hero-unit">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar">
            
                <div class="navbar-inner">
                      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      </a>
                      
                    <a href="#" class="brand">RialedUp</a>
                    
                    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- end navbar -->
            
            <div id="bannerCarousel" class="carouselBanner slide">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="active-item">
                        <div class="hero-unit-inner text-center">
                            <h1>We build well designed websites</h1>
                            <h4>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra.</h4>
                            
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Get Started!</a>
                            <a href="#">Learn More</a>
                            <div>&nbsp;</div>
                                
                            <img src="img/browser.png" alt="Browser" />
                        </div><!-- end hero-unit-inner -->
                    </div><!-- end item -->
                    
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="hero-unit-inner text-center">
                            <h1>We build well designed websites</h1>
                            <h4>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra.</h4>
                            
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Get Started!</a>
                            <a href="#">Learn More</a>
                                
                            <img src="img/browser.png" alt="Browser" />
                        </div><!-- end hero-unit-inner -->
                    </div><!-- end item -->
                    
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="hero-unit-inner text-center">
                            <h1>We build well designed websites</h1>
                            <h4>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra.</h4>
                            
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Get Started!</a>
                            <a href="#">Learn More</a>
                                
                            <img src="img/browser.png" alt="Browser" />
                        </div><!-- end hero-unit-inner -->
                    </div><!-- end item -->
                </div><!-- end carousel inner -->
                <a class="carousel-control left" href="#bannerCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
                <a class="carousel-control right" href="#bannerCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
            </div><!-- end bannerCarousel --> 
            
            
            
        </div>       
    </section><!-- end hero-unit -->
    
    <section id="process">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
            
                <div class="h-line hidden-phone">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="span3">
                    <div class="plan text-center">
                        <span class="process-icon iplan">&nbsp;</span>
                        <h4 class="heading">Plan</h4>
                        <p>This is Photoshops version of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibhid elit.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="span3">
                    <div class="design text-center">
                        <span class="process-icon idesign">&nbsp;</span>
                        <h4 class="heading">Design</h4>
                        <p>This is Photoshops version of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibhid elit.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="span3">
                    <div class="develop text-center">
                        <span class="process-icon idevelop">&nbsp;</span>
                        <h4 class="heading">Develop</h4>
                        <p>This is Photoshops version of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibhid elit.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="span3">
                    <div class="launch text-center">
                        <span class="process-icon ilaunch">&nbsp;</span>
                        <h4 class="heading">Launch</h4>
                        <p>This is Photoshops version of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibhid elit.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>  
        </div>
    </section><!-- end process -->
    
    <section id="portfolio">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                
                <div class="span3">
                    <div class="p-item">
                        <h4 class="heading">Portfolio</h4>
                        <p>This is Photoshops version of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibhid elit.</p>
                        <strong><a href="#">Our Portfolio</a></strong>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="span3">
                    <div class="p-item">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <img src="img/thumbnail/thumb-1.png" class="img-polaroid" alt="Web Design" />
                            <h5 class="title">LeafireDesigns</h5>
                            <small class="category">Web Design</small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="span3">
                    <div class="p-item">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <img src="img/thumbnail/thumb-2.png" class="img-polaroid" alt="Web Development" />
                            <h5 class="title">Unity</h5>
                            <small class="category">Web Development</small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="span3">
                    <div class="p-item">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <img src="img/thumbnail/thumb-3.png" class="img-polaroid" alt="Logo Design" />
                            <h5 class="title">Ingenious</h5>
                            <small class="category">Logo Design</small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </section><!-- end portfolio -->
    
    <section id="partners">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span3 text-center">
                    <img src="img/thumbnail/partner-1.png" alt="Graphic Driver" />
                </div>
                
                <div class="span3 text-center">
                    <img src="img/thumbnail/partner-2.png" alt="Theme Forest" />
                    
                </div>
                
                <div class="span3 text-center">
                    <img src="img/thumbnail/partner-3.png" alt="Code Canyon" />
                    
                </div>
                
                <div class="span3 text-center">
                    <img src="img/thumbnail/partner-4.png" alt="Active Den" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section><!-- end partners -->
    
    <section id="widgets">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
            
                <div class="span4">
                    <div class="testimonials">
                        <h4 class="heading">Testimonials</h4>
                        
                        <div id="testimonialCarousel" class="carouselTestimonial">
                             <div class="carousel-inner">
                                 <div class="active item">
                                     <img src="img/thumbnail/small-thumb-1.png" class="pull-left" alt="Moron" />
                                     <blockquote>
                                         <p>This is Photoshops version of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibhid elit. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibhid elit.</p>
                                         <cite>Moe Ron <br />
                                         <a href="#">www.moron.com</a>
                                         </cite>
                                     </blockquote>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="item">
                                     <img src="img/thumbnail/small-thumb-1.png" class="pull-left" alt="Moron" />
                                     <blockquote>
                                         <p>This is Photoshops version of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibhid elit. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibhid elit.</p>
                                         <cite>Moe Ron <br />
                                         <a href="#">www.moron.com</a>
                                         </cite>
                                     </blockquote>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="item">
                                     <img src="img/thumbnail/small-thumb-1.png" class="pull-left" alt="Moron" />
                                     <blockquote>
                                         <p>This is Photoshops version of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibhid elit. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibhid elit.</p>
                                         <cite>Moe Ron <br />
                                         <a href="#">www.moron.com</a>
                                         </cite>
                                     </blockquote>
                                 </div>
                    
                             </div><!-- end carousel-inner -->
                        </div><!-- end testimonialCarousel -->
                       
                        
                        
                    </div><!-- end testimonials -->
                </div>
                
                <div class="span4">
                    <div class="blog">
                        <h4 class="heading">Our Latest Posts</h4>
                        <ul class="blog-lists">
                            <li>
                                <h5><a href="#">This is Photoshops version of Lorem Ipsum</a></h5>
                                <small>October 4, 2017 | Posted by <a href="#">Admin</a></small>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <h5><a href="#">This is Photoshops version of Lorem Ipsum</a></h5>
                                <small>October 3, 2017 | Posted by <a href="#">Admin</a></small>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <h5><a href="#">This is Photoshops version of Lorem Ipsum</a></h5>
                                <small>October 2, 2017 | Posted by <a href="#">Admin</a></small>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- end blog -->
                </div>
                
                <div class="span3">
                    <div class="tweets">
                        <h4 class="heading">Latest Tweets</h4>
                         <ul class="tweet-lists">
                            <li class="clearfix">
                                <img src="img/thumbnail/small-thumb-2.png" class="pull-left" alt="Clown" />
                                <p>Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor a iquet. <a href="#">http://this.is.me247</a></p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="clearfix">
                                <img src="img/thumbnail/small-thumb-2.png" class="pull-left" alt="Clown" />
                                <p>Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor a iquet. <a href="#">http://this.is.me247</a></p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="clearfix">
                                <img src="img/thumbnail/small-thumb-2.png" class="pull-left" alt="Clown" />
                                <p>Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor a iquet. <a href="#">http://this.is.me247</a></p>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- end tweets-->
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </section><!-- end widgets -->
    
    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
            
                <div class="span12 text-center">
            
                <div class="table">
                <ul class="footer-links">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
                
                <div id="social">
                    <a href="#" class="btn twitter"><span class="social-sprite twitter">&nbsp;</span>Follow Us on Twitter</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn facebook"><span class="social-sprite facebook">&nbsp;</span>Like Us on Facebook</a>
                </div>
                
                <small> &copy; <a href="#">Rialed Up </a>2017</small>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

Comment: Your code has a bunch of errors when we try to run it. You should fix that first.

Comment: remove coma in the end `$('.carouselBanner').carousel(),`

Comment: also is </footer> the end of your code?

Comment: Hi. I deleted the comma, but that didn't change anything. Yes, </footer> is the end of my code and then Javascript begins. I tried copying and pasting the code given below, but that code messed up my page. Plus, it deleted the slider controls. Any other ways to get the slider working?

Comment: Sorry. I am learning Bootstrap as I go along. This is my first web page built from a PSD file.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 <div id="bannerCarousel" class="carouselBanner slide">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="active-item">
```

to

```
<div id="bannerCarousel" class="carouselBanner slide">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="active item"> <!-- active item not active-item -->
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jv6xzgm6/

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your input. Your fiddle definitely shows the carousel slide moving automatically, but your fiddle is doing exactly what my webpage is already doing. When you press the slide right or slide left arrow buttons at the top of your fiddle, the page moves down instead of going to the next slide. Any idea how to get the slide buttons to move the slide left or right instead of just moving the page down when they're pressed?

Comment: I replaced my code with your code and nothing changed.

Comment: Hey, everyone. I gave up on the carousels and just deleted them. Thanks for your help anyway.